# Azure App Service CORS MissingAllowOriginHeader Error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have a Web Application and Web API (both .NET Core) hosted in Azure App service. The Web API is behind Azure App Gateway. The Web App's client side script calls the Web API (HTTP PUT) through the app Gateway endpoint which results in a CORS policy error.

The Web API has the below code in the startup.cs.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {                                          
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().Build();
                                  });
            });
```

The App Gateway has a ReWrite rule configured as follows:

```
If Access-Control-Request-Method == "PUT", then set the Response Headers:  
access-control-allow-headers: content-type 
access-control-allow-methods: PUT 
access-control-allow-origin: https://webappurl
```

With this configuration, I can see that the Pre-flight OPTIONS request gets a 200 response with the above headers in the response. However, the subsequent HTTP PUT request to https://apipurl results in an error:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Error: MissingAllowOriginHeader

As an additional step, I also added the Web App URI to Web API App Service's allowed origins:

```
az webapp cors add --resource-group testrg --name appsvcwebapi --allowed-origins 'https://webappurl'
```

Why is this CORS error still showing up despite the Pre-Flight HTTP 200 response and the access-control-allow-* response headers?

Answer (score -2):

Try with adding the **CORS services**. In the `Configure` method of your `startup.cs`.

Example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

 app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

    }
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-allowed-origins)

And also  try with setting  the `access-control-allow-origin` in correct way

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
```

OR

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://www.my-domain.com
```